# What is the best way to reverse port forward information from a Kubernetes cluster to localhost?

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding, tcpserver

I am attempting to reverse port forward information from a Kubernetes pod **192.168.49.2:30085** to my **locoalhost:8000** but I am having issues.

The goal is to get the same response as `curl 192.168.49.2:30085`  on localhost:8000

One thing I have tried has been using [ktunnel](https://github.com/omrikiei/ktunnel) with the command `ktunnel expose <service_name> 30085:8000` to try to forward this info. Doing this I get the output

```
INFO[0000] Exposed service's cluster ip is: 10.101.77.99
.INFO[0000] waiting for deployment to be ready
.....
INFO[0001] port forwarding to https://192.168.49.2:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/thisisatest-59d5584c84-b5qrc/portforward
INFO[0001] Waiting for port forward to finish
INFO[0001] Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:28688 -> 28688
INFO[2022-08-03 20:23:48.605] starting tcp tunnel from source 30085 to target 8000
```

Which seems normal and I am able to get a response when using `curl http://10.101.77.99:30085`  on local host 8000 but not the correct response.

I have also attempted to run a tcp server with the [command](https://webapp.io/blog/container-tcp-tunnel/) `nc 127.0.0.1 8000 | kubectl exec -i <pod_name> tcpserver 127.0.0.1 30085 cat` But am having poor results as well. Am I using these services incorrectly? Or is there a better way to do this all together?

Comment: How is the question related to docker? --- While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but network-related, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).